Force ThreadSanitizer to crash after finding a problem
I'm running ThreadSanitizer with -02 and g compiler flags and without gdb. It detects the race condition and prints the stacktraces but it continues running. I was fortunate to be monitoring.
Is there a way to force ThreadSanitizer to crash when it detects a problem?

You can use the halt_on_error option:
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -fsanitize=thread
$ TSAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1 ./foo




Flag name
Default value
Description




halt_on_error
0
Exit after first reported error



If you'd rather have this turned on by default. Add a __tsan_default_options function to the program:
#ifdef __SANITIZE_THREAD__
extern "C" const char* __tsan_default_options() {
    return "halt_on_error=1";
}
#endif


Unfortunately the coded solution didn't seem to work. I added it to my main.cpp, compiled with thread sanitizer enabled. But I saw some output with no crash.

@intrigued_66 The coded version does the same as setting the options via the environment variable. If you combine them the environment variable wins.
